# SSAS - YTD SUM with other dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx

I would like to have a calculated measure (rolling_sum) that sums up all the values up to a selected month in the year and I would like to be able to query this measure without the date dimension.

So, I have the following calculated member:

```
     SUM(YTD(),[Measures].[Value])
```

Querying this measure works fine when the query includes the date dimension, however I would like to be able to query this measure by other dimensions without the date dimension.

Would this be possible?

Comment: But it is Year To Date. So you have to provide a Date, even if it is today's date. You could write a measure to show the total only for today's date (or any given member in your date dimension) if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: But lets say that the date is provided in the pivot filter and not in the dimension, how would you sum the [Measures].[Value] up until the date selected in the pivot filter.

Comment: That will still work. YTD will sum up to the current member of the Date dimension, whether it is in rows or the filter.